# Javascript - too much recursion when executing long chain of promises

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, promise, jquery-deferred

I have a long sequence of asynchronous functions to be executed sequentially. So I used promises to create promise queue. Unfortunately on Firefox 25.0.1 on Linux I'm getting `too much recursion` JavaScript error. It works fine on the same Firefox version on Mac, it works in chrome as well. But I need it working everywhere, including Linux. Can you propose better implementation of `executePromiseQueueSync` function?

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function executePromiseQueueSync(queue){
     var seed = $.Deferred(); 
     var acc = seed;

     for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; ++i )
     {
         var promise = queue[i];
         acc = acc.then(promise.funct.apply(null, promise.argmnt));
     }

    seed.resolve();
    return acc;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function someTask(){
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    dfd.notify();
    dfd.resolve();
    return dfd.promise();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$(function(){
    var promisesQueue = []

    for(var i = 0; i < 200; ++i){
        promisesQueue.push({funct:someTask, argmnt:[]});
    }

    executePromiseQueueSync(promisesQueue).then(function(){alert('done!');});
});

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

JSFiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/C2YN4/4/

**What I have so far** (and I'm very open to other propositions and corrections):

```
function executePromiseQueueSync(queue){

    if (queue.length > TRESHOLD){
        var i,j;
        var shortQueue = []
        for (i=0,j=queue.length; i<j; i+=TRESHOLD) {
          temparray = queue.slice(i, i+TRESHOLD);
          shortQueue.push({funct:executePromiseQueueSync, argmnt:[temparray]});
        }
        return executePromiseQueueSync(shortQueue);
    }

    var seed = $.Deferred(); 
    var acc = seed;

    for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; ++i )
    {
         var promise = queue[i];
         acc = acc.then(promise.funct.apply(null, promise.argmnt));
    }

    seed.resolve();
    return acc;
}
```

So the basic idea is to make a promise tree instead of promise chain. This way we don't go so much deep into stack.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/fMBJK/1/

Comment: Why does `promise.funct` get called when it does not return a function? It looks like you are passing promises to `.then()`, which is invalid

Comment: Why are you using promises if `someTask` is synchronous?

Comment: @Bergi - you can remove promise from someTask() and problem will remain.

Comment: Is it required to use promises? Or do you just want to execute the chain in order while waiting for the previous function to finish?

Comment: @Bergi - Imagine you would like to execute some ajax calls in sequence. Is that example enough for you?

Comment: @Yoshi - Yes, I want to execute chain of asynchronous functions (AJAX calls for example). It doesn't have to be implemented with promises but I don't know anything better.

Comment: @mnowotka: If `someTask` would create a function that returns an *A*JAX promise then your code would work flawless. Can you show your actual code?

Comment: @Bergi - I say - whatever you put inside someTask - AJAX, reading from FileReader object or just plain synchronous function not returning a promise you will have this error. You have ACTUAL code as jsfiddle and you are free to provide yours as an example.

Comment: @mnowotka: [Here is a modification of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/C2YN4/6/) that does actually wait (50 times per 100ms)

Comment: @Bergi - yes, I take your modification, change 50 to 200 and I'm getting 'too much recursion' error.

Comment: But what functions are on your call stack then? Everything is fired from the `setTimeout`, and does not nest deeper than about 10.

Comment: @Bergi - is this discussion really necessary? After those few hours I managed to get correct answer and you didn't even got what the problem is.

Comment: A well-written promise library should not exhibit such problems so I'm a little curious about it. I cannot reproduce the problem (as you say, it happens only in special environmental settings), so you should give more details about the error that does happen (line number at least, (shortened) stack trace). Btw, the accepted answer is not a very good one - it does not care about error handling.

Comment: @Bergi - I agree. I've spend two days tracking this problem in my application. The error says literally 'too much recursion' and it occurs in different lines inside jQuery code. What is even more interesting I couldn't get stack trace as all breakopins are ignored (for unknown reasons) when this error occurs.  Believe me, I know how to use Firebug... On the other I managed to isolate problem and having linux box with firefox is relatively easy so you can reproduce it. I can make a screenshot if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `jQuery.when` ~ although it might be a little bit mad passing in over 200 arguments:

http://jsfiddle.net/6j6em/1/

#### The code from the fiddle

**JavaScript with jQuery**

```
var resolves = [];

function log(msg){
  $('#log').append('<div><small>' + msg + '</small></div>');
}

function someTask(i){
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();
  log('created task '+i);
  resolves.push(function(){
    log('resolved task '+i);
    dfd.resolve();
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}

$(function(){

  $('#resolve1').click(function(){
    for ( var i=0; i<resolves.length; i++ ) {
      resolves[i]();
    }
  });

  $('#resolve2').click(function(){
    for ( var i=0; i<resolves.length; i++ ) {
      if ( i == 5 ) continue;
      resolves[i]();
    }
  });

  $('#resolve3').click(function(){
    resolves[5]();
  });

  var i, queue = []; for(i=0; i<200; ++i){ queue.push(someTask(i)); }

  (jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, queue))
    .done(function(){
      log('all resolved!');
      alert('all resolved!');
    })
  ;

});
```

**Markup for this example**

```
<button id="resolve1">Resolve all</button>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="resolve2">Resolve (all but one)</button>
<button id="resolve3">Resolve (the remaining one)</button>
<div id="log"></div>
```

**CSS for this example**

```
#log {
    border: 1px solid black; 
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 200px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

#### Explanation

Much of the above code is just to illustrate, the key points are:

```
  var i, queue = []; for(i=0; i<200; ++i){ queue.push(someTask(i)); }

  (jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, queue))
    .done(function(){
      log('all resolved!');
      alert('all resolved!');
    })
  ;
```

The above generates an array of promise objects, and then using `apply` passes them to `jQuery.when` which then handles creating the correct structure to trigger a `done` callback once they have all completed. That is if you want this kind of behavior. If you want a system that will wait for each promise object to resolve in order, before triggering the next task, you'll need something different.

#### Update

In terms of firing tasks in sequence you need a different approach, something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6j6em/2/

```
function log(msg){
  $('#log').append('<div><small>' + msg + '</small></div>');
}

function someTask(i){
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();
  log(':: created task '+i);
  setTimeout(function(){
    log(':: resolved task '+i);
    dfd.resolve();
  },50);
  return dfd.promise();
}

$(function(){

  var Queue;

  Queue = function( items ){ 
    this.items = items.slice(0);
    this.promise = $.Deferred();
  };
  Queue.prototype.next = function(){
    log(':: next task triggered');
    var q = this;
    q.lastItem = q.items.shift();
    if ( q.lastItem ) {
      q.lastPromise = q.lastItem.func.apply( null, q.lastItem.args );
      q.lastPromise.then(function(){
        /// include a setTimeout 0 to avoid possible stack/recursion errors.
        setTimeout(function(){
          q.next();
        },0);
      });
    }
    else {
      /// we are finished
      q.promise.resolve();
    }
  };
  Queue.prototype.run = function(){
    this.next();
  };

  var i, items = []; for(i=0; i<200; ++i){ 
    items.push({ func: someTask, args:[i] });
  }

  var q = new Queue( items );
  q.promise.done(function(){
    log(':: done!');
    alert('Done!');
  });
  q.run();

});
```

This builds a bespoke `Queue` object that keeps track of the list of promises, and after the first is successful, triggers the next. This code obviously requires error handling however.

#### update x2

You can't rely on progress for each promise because there is only one being triggered at any one time. You can add your own notification call out to the overall `$.Deferred()` object however.

```
var Queue;
Queue = function( items ){ 
  this.items = items.slice(0);
  this.promise = $.Deferred();
  this.count = 0;
};
Queue.prototype.next = function(){
  log(':: next task triggered');
  var q = this;
  q.lastItem = q.items.shift();
  if ( q.lastItem ) {
    q.lastPromise = q.lastItem.func.apply( null, q.lastItem.args );
    q.lastPromise.then(function(){
      q.promise.notify(q.count++);
      q.next();
    });
  }
  else {
    q.promise.resolve();
  }
};
Queue.prototype.run = function(){
  this.next();
};
var q = new Queue( items );
q.promise
  .done(function(){log(':: done!');})
  .progress(function(p){log('::progress ' + p);})
;
q.run();
```

Comment: @mnowotka ~ no it isn't, most often you use promises because you don't know the order in which things will occur. It wasn't clear from you question which was required. I'll need to update with the other approach.

Comment: @mnowotka ~ I've added an update. This code will fire the tasks in sequence.

Comment: Actually it seems to work even if you remove setTimeout. Nice!

Comment: @mnowotka ~ The problem is because you are essentially triggering one task/promise after the other, progress wont be trackable on each promise. You can enhance the code above to bring it back into play for the overall Queue object however ... see my edit.

Comment: I sorted it out. Everything works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW... I'm a bit late, but here is my implementation of your queue requirement:

```
function RunnablePromise(func, args, thisArg) {
    var def = $.Deferred(), prm = def.promise();

    prm.run = function () {
        func.apply(thisArg, args).done(def.resolve).fail(def.reject);
        return prm;
    };
    return prm;
}

function PromiseQueue() {
    var q = [], overall = $.Deferred(), self = this;

    this.run = function () {
        var runnable = q.shift();
        if (runnable) {
            overall.notify(q.length);
            runnable.run().done(self.run).fail(overall.reject);
        } else {
            overall.resolve();
        }
        return overall.promise();
    };
    this.append = function (task, args, thisArg) {
        var runnable = new RunnablePromise(task, args, thisArg);
        q.push(runnable);
        return runnable;
    };
}
```

Used like this:

```
var pq = new PromiseQueue(), i,
    success = function (i) { console.log("task done: " + i); };

for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    // .append() returns the individual task's promise
    pq.append(someAsyncTask, [i]).done(success);
}

// .run() returns the entire queue's promise
pq.run().progress(function (remain) {
    console.log("remaining: " + remain);
}).done(function () {
    console.log("all done!");
}).fail(function () {
    console.log("error!");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CxNDv/

Comment: Thanks for your solution, can you comment on it? Why is it better then the one accepted?

Comment: Well, for one, it is shorter. ;) I also think it's more readable; the concept being roughly the same. But ultimatlely: I had an answer in the works and was interrupted before I could finish, but didn't want to throw it away just because I was late.